# Does sniper's eye allow sneak attack damage with splash damage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, rogue, sneak-attack, alchemist

Can an alchemist/rogue with the rogue talent [sniper's eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/rogue-talents/paizo-rogue-talents/sniper-s-eye-ex/) deal sneak attack damage with his [bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/#TOC-Bomb-Su-)'s splash damage?

Comment: I know there is the Archtype: Undergound Chemist: which allows at level 4 to get that ability but our DM did not allow archtypes to come into play until after a key point in the campaign and only when we have to make a new character  --- [http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue/archetypes/paizo---rogue-archetypes/underground-chemist/ ] link for Underground Chemist

Comment: You're welcome. Just cutting to the chase. And a heads-up: Don't worry about a downvote or two just because "[s]plash weapons cannot deal precision-based damage" ([here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Throw-Splash-Weapon)); I think this is a *great* specific *versus* general question considering the *very* specific language of sniper's eye!

Answer (score 10):

No, [splash weapons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/combat.html#throw-splash-weapon) are explicitly denied precision damage.

> Splash weapons cannot deal precision-based damage (such as sneak attack).

The rogue talent [Sniper's Eye](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/coreClasses/rogue.html#sniper%27s-eye) only removes the prohibition against precision damage if the target benefits from concealment. It doesn't change the way that splash weapons work or affect anything other than the bolded parts below. It certainly does not allow carte blanche sneak attack with all ranged weapons.

> **Sneak Attack**: ... The rogue must be able to see the target well enough to pick out a vital spot and must be able to reach such a spot. **A rogue cannot sneak attack while striking a creature with concealment.**
>
> **Sniper's Eye (Ex)**: A rogue with this talent can apply her sneak attack damage on ranged attacks targeting foes within 30 feet **that benefit from concealment**. Foes with total concealment are still immune.

There is a rogue archetype, [Underground Chemist](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedClassGuide/classOptions/rogue.html#underground-chemist-archetype), which does explicitly allow precision damage with splash weapons, but only under certain narrow circumstances. It doesn't allow precision damage on top of the weapon's splash damage, however, only to the primary target and only on the first attack per round. If you threw two bombs in a round, and missed with the first but hit with the second, you would deal only the base bomb damage.

> **Precise Splash Weapons (Ex)**: At 4th level, an underground chemist can deal sneak attack damage with splash weapons. The attack must be her first attack in that round, must qualify to be a sneak attack (such as an attack against a flat-footed target), and must be directed at a creature rather than a square. This ability replaces the rogue talent gained at 4th level.